# Updating xaxis with celluloid camera python animation

Tags: python, animation, camera, axis

I want to make an animation where the x-axis gets updated, using celluloid.camera.snap()
As the timeseries is quite long the animation.FuncAnimation is not ideal (got that running now, so not even sure if that works).
I have tried to add `blit = False` and a few other things. But the x-axis stays the same with the lines moving through the plot. As I want to plot a few years of data, I want it to update the x-axis to the 5 days I plot each frame.

```
start = datetime(2014,12,1,0,0,0)
ds_start = datetime(2014,12,12,0,0,0)
time = pd.date_range(start = start, freq = 'd', periods = len(RS.time))
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d')

for t in range(20):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (11,8),)
    camera = Camera(fig)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)
    gs = fig.add_gridspec(5, 13)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:3, :9], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:, :9])
    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:3, 10:])
   
    ax.set_extent((162.,169.94, -78.5, -74.25), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
       
    gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), linewidth=1, color='black', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--', draw_labels=True)
    gl.top_labels = False
    gl.left_labels = True
    gl.right_labels=False
    gl.xlines = True
    gl.xlabel_style = {'color': 'black', 'size': 15}
    gl.ylabel_style = {'color': 'black', 'size': 15}
    # ax.text(163,-74,time[t].strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), fontsize = 15)
    
    
    
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    
    
    for t in range(15,25):# short period just to test the function
        ax.set_title(time[t].strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), fontsize = 15)
        im = ax.contourf(RS.Longitude,RS.Latitude,RS.SeaIceConcentration[t], cmap = 'PuBu_r', levels = np.arange(0,101,10))
        ds.SA.sel(depth = 75,time = slice(time[t-2],time[t+3])).plot(ax=ax2, c = 'darkblue', alpha = 0.3)
        ds.CT.sel(depth = 75,time = slice(time[t-2],time[t+3])).plot(ax=ax1, c = 'darkgreen', alpha = 0.3)
            
        ds.T.sel(depth =115,time = slice(time[t-2],time[t+3])).plot(ax=ax1, c = 'olivedrab', alpha = 0.3)
        ds.T.sel(depth =155,time = slice(time[t-2],time[t+3])).plot(ax=ax1, c = 'olivedrab', alpha = 0.4)
        ds.T.sel(depth =195,time = slice(time[t-2],time[t+3])).plot(ax=ax1, c = 'olivedrab', alpha = 0.5)
        ds.T.sel(depth =235,time = slice(time[t-2],time[t+3])).plot(ax=ax1, c = 'olivedrab', alpha = 0.6)
        
        ds.SA.sel(depth =275,time = slice(time[t-2],time[t+3])).plot(ax=ax2, c = 'darkblue', alpha = 0.7)
        ds.CT.sel(depth =275,time = slice(time[t-2],time[t+3])).plot(ax=ax1, c = 'darkgreen', alpha = 0.7)
            
        ds.SA.sel(depth = 668,time = slice(time[t-2],time[t+3])).plot(ax=ax2, c = 'darkblue', alpha = 1)
        ds.CT.sel(depth = 668,time = slice(time[t-2],time[t+3])).plot(ax=ax1, c = 'darkgreen', alpha = 1)
            
        ax1.axvline(time[t], c = 'black',alpha = 0.3)
        ax1.axvline(time[t+1], c = 'black',alpha = 0.3)
        
        
        
        ax1.set_ylabel('Con. Temperature [$\degree$C]', c = 'darkgreen')
        ax1.set_xlabel(' ')
        ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='darkgreen')
        ax2.set_ylabel('Abs. Salinity [g/kg]', c = 'darkblue')
        ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='darkblue')
        ax2.invert_yaxis()
        ax1.set_title('  ')
        ax2.set_title('  ')
        ax1.set_xlim(time[t-2],time[t+3])      
        
        wind = MW_days.sel(time = slice(time[t-2],time[t+3]))
        ax3.bar(wind.time,wind.windspeed, color = 'tab:blue')
        ax3.set_ylabel('windspeed [m/s]')
        ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
        camera.snap()
        ax1.legend(loc=1,bbox_to_anchor=(1.44, 1.05),title = 'C. Temperature')
        ax2.legend(loc=1,bbox_to_anchor=(1.44, .15), title = 'A. Salinity')
            
    
        
plt.colorbar(im, label = 'Sea Ice Concentration')
ax.stock_img()
animation = camera.animate()

animation.save(figure_path+'t.gif', writer = 'pillow')
```

even though I have the ax.set_lim(...) within the forloop, it does not update it each frame.
I have tried a lot of different things,

Tried:

`ani = FuncAnimation(fig,animate, blit = False)`
this takes a very long time and has not solved the issue, (put the for loop in a function called animate)

`animation = camera.animate(blit = False )` This did not change anything